# Solving two dimensional Heat equation PDE in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations, pde, heat, wolframalpha

I am trying to solve the following equation in Mathematica but I do not know each time it only returns the equation itself instead of solving it. I tried both Dsolve and NDsolve and it was not helping me. Could anyone help me with the correct syntax?
There is a symmetry boundary condition there and the equation is in cylindrical r and z and depends on time t too.

```
heat= (1/r)*D[r*T[r, z, t], r] + 
D[T[r, z, t], {z, 2}] == (1/(10^-4))*D[T[r, z, t], t]
NDSolve[{heat, T[0.05, z, 0] == 500, D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0}, 
T, {r, 0.01, 0.05}, {t, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 0.05}]
```

I did the same with Dsolve and no success. 
If this question is not related to here would you guide me where and how to post it before you deactivate it? thank you

Comment: if `D[T[r, z, t], r]` is zero you should reduce this to a 1d transient problem yourself.  mathematica.stackexchange.com is a better place

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean exactly. That condition comes from symmetry. How can I simplify or reduce my problem to 1d? The point here is that this problem has heat transfer in z direction too but If I want to apply the symmetry are you saying D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0 is wrong?

Comment: symmetry where?  Your statement says no r  dependence for all z and t.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130768/solving-two-dimensional-heat-equation-pde-in-mathematica

Comment: @agentp Thank you. I posted this on Mathematica section too. I have two coaxial cylinders. The symmetry is around r=0 axis. Which means derivative of the temperature to r is zero.

Comment: `r=0` is not even in your domain, 0.01 , 0.05 , but if it was d/dr would naturally be zero due to the 1/r dt/dr term, you dont need a condition there. Your first term in your `heat` expression is wrong too. Any textbook on pde's will cover this problem

Comment: You are right I changed {r, 0.01, 0.05} because I thought the reason it does not solve is the singular point at r=0 so I changed it to 0.01. when @agentp I posted it I forgot to change it. Thank you for reminding me of that. For my first term you said it is wrong. Do you mean it is wrong in terms of Mathematica or PDE? That is in cylindrical format and I have seen it in thermal books. I actually derived it from there. I do not understand why you said it is wrong.

Comment: you should have a second derivative in r when you expand the first term

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand why we should have second derivative for symmetry.  D[T[r, z, t], r] == 0 is the first derivative.